# "Type DataGrid in CSS selector 'DataGrid' must be qualified with a namespace" warning when styling in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, styling

I am attempting to style the headers in a flex datagrid and I keep getting the warning:

> Type DataGrid in CSS selector 'DataGrid' must be qualified with a namespace

What does this mean? I have gone through a bunch of tutorials and none of them have worked.  It seems like changing a the colors in a datagrid should be relatively simple.

Here is a code sample:

```
<mx:Style>
    .headerCustomStyle
    {
        fontWeight: "bold";
        textAlign: "center";
        color: #0000FF;
    }

    DataGrid {
        alternating-item-colors: #F4FBFF, #FFFFFF;
    }
</mx:Style>

<mx:DataGrid draggableColumns="true" width="100%" id="topTracks" headerStyleName="headerCustomStyle" dataProvider="{_trackData.track}" >
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn id="artistName" dataField="artist.name" headerText="Artist" width="250" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn id="trackName" dataField="name" headerText="Track" width="250"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Flex 4, you need to define namespaces like this:

```
@namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo";
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
@namespace tlf "library://ns.adobe.com/flashx/textLayout";

/* Halo DataGrid */
mx|DataGrid
{
...
}

/* Spark Button */
s|Button
{
...
}
```

They might be referring to that if you're using a new version of Flex/Flash Builder.  Not sure if Flex 3 requires namespaces though.

Here's Adobe's doc on [CSS Namespace Support](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/CSS+Namespaces+Support)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Flex 4, you normally DO NOT use CSS at all.
You think I'm telling tales?

Well, read this:
http://www.adobe.com/content/dotcom/en/devnet/flex/articles/migrating-flex-apps-part2.html

Port your Flex 4 applications to CSS-free code and you won't have any of these problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why its telling you that you need a namespace, but in your CSS, `DataGrid` is a type.

So try and give it the fully qualified namespace for DataGrid (`mx.controls.DataGrid`)